# Operator norm is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Is that always true?

$$\left\|\lim_{n}\,T_{n}\right\|=\lim_{n}\,\left\|T_{n}\right\|$$

where $T_{n}$ is linear operator.  Thanks.

Comment: If $\lim_{n}T_{n}$ exists in the operator norm, then the answer is "yes."

Comment: why? triangle inequality?

Comment: Reverse triangle inequality $|\|T_{n}\|-\|T\||\le \|T_{n}-T\|$. So, if $T_{n}\rightarrow T$ in the operator norm, then $\|T_{n}\|$ converges to $\|T\|$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the limit exists, yes it is true. Thats because the norm is a continuous function by construction (i.e. the space topology is generated by the open balls in this norm) and for every continuous function between topological spaces $\lim f(x_n)=f(\lim x_n)$

Comment: @TKM Is there anything else you want to prove? Something you didnt understand here?